# Question edit made answer off-topic - what to do with that answer?

Tags: discussion, edits

Let's say there is a question. It was ambiguous. Only for one user it wasn't and he answered. And then question got clarified. It cannot even count as drastic edit. It left answer looking off-topic, low quality. So it's either upvoted by people who knows how the question looked earlier (bad for future readers), or downvoted by ones looking at "now" (bad for honest user who answered). Is there any way to deal with these situations?

Comment: This is why you vote to close unclear questions, rather than trying to answer them.  Also, please link to the relevant question.

Comment: @Servy I'm not talking about me. I can link that particular question, if it matters. But my concern are newbies who may not know that yet.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't think it's exactly a duplicate - question you mentioned is about drastic edits that are discouraged. Clarifications are encouraged. I agree link you provided may help, of course, simply situation described is different.

Comment: @Mołot They should be able to figure it out quickly enough.  In any case you wouldn't really treat it differently; if you encourage the bad behavior then they won't realize or care that it's undesirable.

Comment: @Servy true enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer should be deleted or edited to correctly answer the question as is.  It clearly doesn't answer the question that's asked as it is, so it shouldn't just be left there.

If the question was indeed unclear then the OP clarifying it wasn't wrong, the problem was that someone decided to take a guess at what the problem was and tried to answer an unclear question.  If you guess right this can be rewarding, but if you guess wrong you're causing problems or at least adding noise; you should just get rid of this post.  This is why you should avoid answering unclear questions, you should simply vote/flag to close the question until it is clarified sufficiently to be answerable.